# How to build Qt project as a standalone executable?

Tags: qt, mingw, exe, executable, static-linking

I tried to build a standalone version of my Qt project. I went through a couple of tutorials regarding the static linking and building. I set up my qtcreator kits. I didn't succeed.

Theoretically, if I provide my project files to somebody who was able to do it for him/herself, he/she should be able to build one .exe for me, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that when all your library used is static and your application is static too. And you must build static version of Qt by you, follow document here:

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW

and here https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

Comment: I downloaded the windows-build-qt-static.ps1 from the first link, right clicked on it and clicked on Run with PowerShell, commadn window popped up, and closed almost immediately. Since then nothing happened. I think it is not doing anything at the moment. 
I also tried the second link, but the instructions (In which directory should I use the commands etc) was not clear, so I couldn't even proceed the first step.

Comment: You can try other option, compile with mingw32, deploy your application with some dll library in application folder and it work fine in other windows version without any dep.

Comment: in your image in http://i.stack.imgur.com/g8iaV.png I can see the problem here. You can try install normal version Qt with mingw first and follow link here to add PATH correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913416/can-not-call-make-clean-in-cmd-regarding-qmake-project/33914038#33914038, after that, try build static Qt again. I hope it will solve your problem